# Array confusion - Quiz

Tags: sorting

I am a bit confused by one of my quiz answers and I was hoping somebody could provide me with an explanation.  The question is:

You have two arrays named b and c. You call a static method that swaps the value in component k of one array with the value in component k of the other array. This swap method does not mention any variable declared outside the method except its parameters. Which of the following method calls could possibly accomplish this?

Answer: swap (c, b, k)

I am very confused why this is the answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the other choices?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely swap's declaration has c and b being passed by reference.  That means all the function has to do is check both to make sure there's enough elements (`sizeof(c) >= k && sizeof(b) >= k` or something similar) before doing the actual swap.

Also: b,c, and k are defined in the question itself.

Comment: And possibly allocate a temporary variable if you can't do simultaneous assingment. `t = c[k]; c[k] = b[k]; b[k] = t`

Answer (score 0):

it swaps the element at index k for both b and c.  k-1 swaps the element which is previous to k and 0 swaps the 1st element in array

Answer (score 0):

Since swap() can't refer to anything outside itself, all the necessary references and information must be passed in as parameters.

The answer of **swap (c, b, k)** is correct since it gives a reference to both arrays and what index to swap.  You just can't accomplish the task passing in fewer parameters.

If you only had **swap ()**, **swap (k)**, or **swap (c, b)**, then the method would need information external to itself to complete the task.